# reset redux enhancer that does not change the shape of the state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have created the following redux enhancer that allows me to take a snapshot of the state and rollback at anytime:

```
export const resetable = (reducer: Function) => {
  const initialState = { current: reducer(undefined, {}), previous: undefined };

  return (state = initialState, action: Action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case ActionTypes.SaveSnapShot:
        return { ...state, previous: state.current };
      case ActionTypes.Rollback:
        return { ...state, current: state.previous, previous: undefined };
      case ActionTypes.Commit:
        return { ...state, previous: undefined };
      default:
        return {
          ...state,
          current: reducer(state.current, action)
        };
    }
  };
};
```

Its usage is like this:

```
export default function createReducer() {
  return combineReducers({
    key: resetable(reducer),
  });
}
```

The problem is that it changes the shape of the passed in reducer's state.

For example if I have state like this:

```
{
  contact: {
    firstName: 'Bob',
    lastName: 'Conman'
  }
}
```

Then it adds `current` and `previous` keys to the state.

So the state becomes:

```
{
  contact: {
    current: {
      firstName: 'Bob',
      lastName: 'Conman'
    },
    previous: undefined
  }
}
```

Is there anyway to provide similar functionality without altering the shape of the state and adding new keys?